# How to see PDF object in TeXworks

Tags: pdftex, texworks

I am a bit new to TeX, and I have searched google for the answer to this question with no luck:

If I make a TeX file in TeXworks like the one shown below, how can I see/save this file in PDF format? I have attempted to save the file as a .pdf, but Adobe Reader does not recognize it and will not open it.

```
\documentclass {article}
\begin{document}
\title{Investigation 7}
\author{John Smith}
\date{6/20/2014}
\end{document}
```

BTW, I have downloaded and installed MacTeX and nothing else.

Comment: Insert `\maketitle` after `\date{}` and compile the file. Click on the green button or your editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no "printable" content in that document yet, thus no output.  Try entering some text after `\begin{document}`.  Also, be sure to select the `pdfLaTeX` dropdown option in the top left of the interface in TeXWorks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use TeXPad. I'm also a Mac user and only using it for two years. It really helped me a lot. Install the TexPad program, and writing your documents, you will see directly your pdf document. (side by side)

Comment: Does the PDF document update automatically?

Comment: No in this program you should tap Cmd-T.
But you can also use the online system www.writelatex.com or www.sharelatex.com 
On those sites you have realtime compiling to pdf.